# Why does <nuxt-link> overwrites my css in Nuxt.js?

Tags: frontend, nuxt.js

I am getting this issue with Nuxt.

Whenever I use , it automatically rewrites my CSS design and shows it differently. You can see exact issue in the video below.

[Video of the issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PoAoJh-Q9OSFWP0ABVj7zLOi3tRSM7Nf/view?usp=sharing)

If I replace `<nuxt-link>` with `<a>`, everything starts to work correctly.

Navbar code example:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark mb-5 text-white" style="z-index: 10; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3)">

<nuxt-link to="/" class="navbar-brand" active-class="active">
  Frontend
</nuxt-link>
<button
  class="navbar-toggler"
  type="button"
  data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#navbarNav"
  aria-controls="navbarNav"
  aria-expanded="false"
  aria-label="Toggle navigation"
>
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" />
</button>
<div id="navbarNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <nuxt-link to="/" class="nav-link" active-class="active">
        Home
      </nuxt-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <nuxt-link to="/games" class="nav-link" active-class="active">
        Games
      </nuxt-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Correct css (at the start of the page loading)
[image: Correct CSS]

Incorrect css (after a few seconds)
[image: Incorrect CSS]

Answer (score 2):

Issue was with `<style>` in index.vue (main page).

Changed it to `<style scoped>` and the issue is fixed.

Comment: I am also running into similar issue, I have posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72198087/7584240 can you please have a look and provide some response? Thanks in advance.